# Libre Office Button Titles are Black

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

When I open a document in Libre Office Writer all the toolbar button's titles are black.
Anyone seen this before?
[image]

I can just barely make out what the text is.

It wasn't this way before and I haven't been messing with any settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Bug report: Bug 40461 - Tooltips get written Black on Black with KDE default theme bound to LibreOffice / https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40461

Workaround:

- http://chakra-project.org/bbs/viewtopic.php?id=5895

> An easier "solution" for this issue is select oxygen cold theme color
>   instead oxygen in System Settings... :-)

- http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/02/18/%23kubuntu-devel.html

> Ezim  that way libreoffice and other gtk application on toolbar tips
>   look so damn ugly oxygen cold solves that problem easy

Comment: I solved this last night by changing the color of "tool tips" in system settings.

Comment: Another Helpful [Link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=123684) on the subject.

Comment: I had to change tool-tips-background, I think LibreOffice is getting most settings from theme but tool-tip-forground is black. (that is how it looks to me). In the end I selected doxgen-cold as it has a light tool-tip-baceground, and I did not wont to invent a new untested theme (risking another colour clash)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a theme color issue with 'tool tips'. Is this only with Libreoffice?

Comment: As far as I can tell its just in Libre Office. I can't find a setting for "tool-tips" or anything like that.